# How to save the intent Extras in Shared prefrences

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, extra

Here is my code which request user for their username:

```
private void request_user_name() {
 final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter name:");

    final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);
    input_field.setText(sharedpreferences.getString("username",""));
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setView(input_field);
    final String savedName = sharedpreferences.getString(username,"");

    input_field.setText(savedName);
    input_field.setSelection(input_field.getText().length());
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            name = input_field.getText().toString();


            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(savedName)) {
                input_field.setError("Your message");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
            }
            editor.putString(username, name);
            editor.apply();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(savedName)) {
                input_field.setError("Your message");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
            }
            else
            {
                dialogInterface.cancel();
                request_user_name();
            }

        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

And this is how I pass he username to next Activity:

```
  intent.putExtra("room_name",((TextView)view).getText().toString() );
            intent.putExtra("user_name",name);
            intent.putExtra("default_name","anyonymous");
            startActivity(intent);
```

And this is how I receive the Intent Extra in next Activity:

```
 if (getIntent().getExtras() != null
            && getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name")!=null) {

        user_name =  getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();

    }else{

        user_name =  getIntent().getExtras().get("default_name").toString();
    }
```

My problem is when users don't enter his name and it returns null then it returns `anyonymous` but when users enter his name then it  pass user name to next activity. But when I restart the app then again it passes `anyonymous` to next activity instead of usernae the user already entered

So I need suggestion on how to save the entered username in shared prefrences and use the same in future launch of app unless new name is not entered instead of `anyonymous`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are already using `SharedPreferences` to store the user_name, then you don't need to pass the `user_name` via `Intent`. `SharedPreferences` are global and could be accessed throughout the application. Just do:

`sharedpreferences.getString("username","anonymous")`

in your target activity.